# Export ASP.NET MVC 5 webpage with jquery-generated content to PDF

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5, export-to-pdf

I have and MVC 5 View, which contains html code as well as some js / jquery scripts.

1) When controller calls the view, view's html content is rendered.

2) Than, scripts starts to work: one ajax calls sql server for some values for dropdowns.

3) When this ajax is completed and dropdown are filled with values (including default values), several ajax queries launch, read dropdowns values and draw some tables (using `<table>`) or charts (using `<canvas>` and chart.js).

After that, page is ready. But if user selects a value from one of the dropdowns, point 3) completes once again, and part of the tables and charts are redrawn.

This architecture is used to provide update only of needed tables/chart and provides quick and interactive user experience. Selecting a parameter from dropdowns does not reload entire page, but only redraws needed div (in frontend).

But when I want to export this page to pdf file using some ASP.NET MVC library, this architecture has led me to a problem. All these libraries (now I'm using Select.Pdf community edition) call a controller method, receive a View, and convert it into pdf file. In my case, if user selects something in dropdowns, gets redrawn page and wants to get it as pdf, the pdf library calls view, and the page is saved as pdf in a default view, withount changes made by user!

Now, the only solution I see is to forget about responsive UX, add 5-10 parameters (one for each dropdown) to controller method, and to read and process this parameters in controller, not in js.

So, the question: Should I switch the project to traditioanal ASP.NET MVC approach? Or should I finally generate a pdf file from js?

Comment: See here: [generate a pdf file from js](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=generate+a+pdf+file+from+js&oq=generate+a+pdf+file+from+js&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l4.254j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)...so yeah in theory you can export to PDF from JS based on the current DOM :-) . What research / attempts have you made so far to try and achieve your requirement?

Comment: I've corrected my question. Of couse, it seems to be some js libs which can make a pdf file and even put html into it :-) Now I will look at jsPDf and makePdf, I hope, they can use css and export `<canvas>`es. But my question likely sounds like - am I right in using client-side approach here?

Comment: well since you are making client-side changes then yes, unless you can find a way to post a record of those change back to your server such that they can then be re-presented into some HTML generated server-side, but that sounds like it would be more trouble that it's worth.

Comment: @ADyson I also thought about cookies to store this information, but low capacity and purpose makes this way like a kind of duct tape :)

Comment: I'm not really sure how thought cookies would help? They live on the client side.

Comment: @ADyson I thought cookies can be read by controller

Comment: Well yes potentially but it's not a place to put the user's data in any case. You would send them in variables like any normal HTTP request.